# How to make UITableViewCell stay at same place after inserting new rows on top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen a lot of questions regrading this.
But I came across a tricky situation. 
If my UITableView only has 1 row and I insert a row on top, it scrolls down to the bottom of the UITableView. I don't want this to happen. It should stays on top itself. So how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

After you insert the new row(s), tell your table view to `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` the new value of your exiting row's index.

```
// Insert new rows.
...
// Create the new index of the current row.
NSInteger newRowIndex = <...>;
NSIndexPath *updatedPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:newRowIndex];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:updatedPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Note that `NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:` assumes that your table has a single section. If you have multiple sections, then you need to use `NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:length:` with an array of index values.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

Comment: It doesn't scroll the tableview at the top of that single row. Means if i call that method its doesn't do that my tableview got extra cell but he will get to know only when he scrolls in case of single row.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, so you could take its `contentOffset`, and (after inserting your rows),

```
[tableView setContentOffset:oldContentOffset + heightOfAddedRows animated:NO];
```

Comment: Already tried that works great if my tableview has some rows before top rows addition but in case of single row it scrolls down the top old single row.

Comment: I'm having difficulty imagining what's happening. Screenshots?